# Можно ли обойтись без класса Entry в классе Мар?

Tags: java, hashmap, entry

У класса Мар есть внутренний класс Entry, который можно получить например методом entrySet().
Какую особую ценность несет этот класс? Можно ли вообще обойтись без него в работе?

Comment: `У класса Мар есть внутренний класс Entry, который можно получить например методом getValue().` - нет, getValue() - это метод класса Entry. Entry - это "контейнер" для пары ключ-значение, который получается при обходе множества, полученного из метода `map.entrySet()`. Ну, можно обойтись без Entry, если получить множество ключей, потом по ключу вытаскивать значение, но это лишние "телодвижения".

Comment: @insolor я опечатался, да имел ввиду функцию entrySet(). Исправил в вопросе.
Вот к примеру две строки кода с однаковым результатом. Первая строка показывает, что можно обойтись без Entry. А есть ли пример где без него не обойтись?

        hs.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println((k + v)));
        for (var kv : hs.entrySet()) System.out.println(kv.getKey() + kv.getValue());

Comment: Никакой разницы. Внутри forEach тоже идет цикл for по парам ключ-значение, только контейнером там является более низкоуровневый объект Node: https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#L1271

Answer (score 1):

- Если нужны пары "ключ-значение", пользуйтесь `Map.Entry<K, V>`, получая из `Map::entrySet`
- Если нужны только ключи (`Set<K>`), их можно получить при помощи `Map::keySet`
- Если нужны только значения (`Collection<V>`), их можно получить при помощи `Map::values`

Answer (score 0):

Entry это не класс. Это интерфейс. В AbstractMap его реализация называется SimpleEntry.

Comment: Есть Set возвращаемый методом entrySet(). Вопрос был, можно ли обойтись без него, другими имеющими средствами у Мар. По поводу названий: Вызов hs.entrySet().getClass() - у меня выдает class java.util.HashMap$EntrySet

Comment: Все верно EntrySet класс есть, который . А Entry это интерфейс.

Comment: ваши комментарии никак не помогают дискуссии. Вопрос не какой класс или интерфейс есть, а что возвращает entrySet().